# How to send upstream messages with FCM from android client? To a Particular Device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
 FirebaseMessaging fm = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance();
            fm.send(new RemoteMessage.Builder(SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com")
                    .setMessageId(Long.toString(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()))
                    .addData("my_message", "Find my phone")
                    .addData("my_action","FIND_MY_PHONE")
                    .build());
```

I use this code segment to send upstream message from android client, but how can i send it to a particular device or register id?

Comment: Nothing as such mentioned in the official docs. I believe you will have to write functions over there on the firebase server and add the logic to act on data changes and notify the appropriate device.

Comment: Using this code segment i can send message. but the message is not yet received in my phone as push message.

Comment: What i could conclude from the docs is that, using the above code segment you could send messages back to server and not to any particular device. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Ashish Kumar Okay Thanks for your replay. Now i understood it. Thanks once again.